# Unique numbers in list

Tags: java

Hello i have a problem with generating 10000000 employees. Everyone has to have unique ID number.

```
List<Employee> employeesL = new LinkedList<>();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        Employee employeeObject = new Employee();
        employeeObject.setId(Math.abs(gen.nextLong()));
        .
        .
        .
        employeesL.add(employeeObject);
        }
```

Is it possible to do it better than simple while loop. I dit something like that:

```
public static void uniqueAdd(List<Employee> employees, Employee employee)
    {
        Random gen = new Random();
        employee.setId(Math.abs(gen.nextLong()));

        while (employees.contains(employee.getId())) {
            employee.setId(Math.abs(gen.nextLong()));
        }
    }
```

The only problem is that it takes forever with that method to generate that amount of employees.
I cant also use simple iteration id++

EDIT:
I need to create uniqueAdd method! My professor gave me advice that i can use Set, for example HashSet

Comment: Why do you want to maintain 1m employees in a linked list in memory?

Comment: This is one of my professor's exercises

Comment: Do you have to use a random ID? Have you learned about hashing and hash based data structures?

Comment: A random number generator is not an ideal way to generate unique IDs because it may generate duplicates so you'll have to check every single generated ID is unique (by doing  a lookup against a hashtable of IDs already in use). Instead, you might want to look at a UUID type of generator.

Comment: I dont have to use random Id.

Comment: @jarmod  It depends on how you do it.  Take a look at my answer.  It works in constant time

Comment: @WJS sure, you can build a solution that *leverages* random numbers, at some cost in either time or space (yours is in space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have done is a non-performant way as you are checking `employees.contains(employee.getId())` every time you want to add an ID. The easiest way will be to create a `static` variable in `Employee` and get the next ID as follows:

```
private static int id = 0;

public static int nextId() {
   return ++id;
}
```

Then,

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    Employee employeeObject = new Employee();
    employeeObject.setId(Employee.nextId());
    .
    .
    .
    employeesL.add(employeeObject);
}
```

You can even assign the `id` in the constructor as follows:

```
this.id = nextId();
```

This way, you do not have to call `employeeObject.setId(Employee.nextId())` when you create an Employee object and a unique `id` will automatically be assigned to the object.

**Alternatively,**

Once you have populated the list, `employeesL`, you can use the following mechanism to set the `id`.

```
Set<Integer> idSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
Random random = new Random();
while (idSet.size() != 10000000) {
    idSet.add(random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
}
System.out.println("10000000 unique IDs generated");

int i = 0;
for (Integer id: idSet) {
    employeesL.get(i).setId(id);
    i++;
}
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Good idea but i cant use simple iteration

Comment: You are most welcome. I would like to know what else you want and I will try my best.

Comment: what about method uniqueAdd that uses Set, for example HashSet? HashSet could store used ids, right? My professor gave this advice.

Comment: I've posted an update. I hope, it fulfils the requirement your professor has given.

Comment: Thanks i will use it !

Comment: I think your approach can be sped up considerably by simply allocating the numbers in a List from 1 to MAX and then shuffling them.  The shuffle routines should work in linear time.  That way you don't have to keep hanging around for that last number to be generated.

Comment: @WJS - OP wanted to use a `HashSet` specifically and shuffling doesn't work for a `Set`. In that case, first, you will need to create a `List` then shuffle it and finally add the `List` to a `HashSet`. This approach will take the same time as mine (I tested both these approaches to be taking 2 seconds for 10M unique IDs). Had there been no preference of using a `HashSet`, allocating the numbers in a List from 1 to MAX and then shuffling them would have definitely been much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of generating a random number and checking if the number is already in the List, you can generate a uuid (universally unique identifier) for each employee, ensuring that the id will not be repeated. There are more ways to generate uuids, but you can do something like this:

```
employeeObject.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
```

Answer (score 1):

If  you initialize a list of id candidates you can allocate them randomly in constant time by using the following approach.  It works by replacing the taken id's slot with the last id in the list. It also removes the last element in the list of possible ids to reduce unnecessary storage.

```
    final static int MAX_IDS = 10_000_000;
    static List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>(MAX_IDS);
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_IDS; i++) {
            ids.add(i + 1);
        }
    }
    final static Random r = new Random();

    public static int getNextID() {
         int idsRemaining = ids.size();
         int index = r.nextInt(idsRemaining);
         int id = ids.get(index);
         int last = ids.get(idsRemaining-1);
         ids.set(index, last);
         ids.remove(idsRemaining-1);
         return id+1;
    }
```

If you want to convince yourself that no duplicates are generated, you can put all the ids in a set.  The set should be the same size as the initial list and have the same ids, but randomly generated.

```
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(MAX_IDS);
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_IDS; i++) {
            set.add(getNextID());
        }
        System.out.println(set.size());
```